# How do I find this integral, in as much detail as possible please?

Tags: integration

How do I find this integral, in as much detail as possible please?

$$\int x \cos (x^2) \,\mathrm dx $$

Comment: Use $u=x^2$ and then use integration by parts.  I believe you can do the rest :).

Comment: @Chinny84 , after putting $u=x^2$, there will be no need for integration by parts

Comment: @MridulSachdeva oops!

Comment: @leiahassan it is good practice to give some idea of what you have already tried when asking a question

Comment: @JoeTait hehe sorry, this is my first time using stack exchange. Thanks for your help everyone. Got it now.

Answer (score 3):

If we put $$u = x^2 $$ then $$ du = 2x\,dx \iff xdx = \frac 12 du$$

Then our integral becomes $$\int \cos \underbrace{(x^2)}_u \,\underbrace{x\;dx}_{\frac 12\; du} = \frac 12 \int \cos(u)\,du = \frac 12 \sin\underbrace{(u)}_{x^2} + C$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=x^2$ so $dt=2xdx$ hence
$$\int x\cos\left( x^2\right)dx=\frac12\int \cos(t)dt=\frac12\sin (t)+C=\frac12\sin\left(x^2\right)+C$$

Comment: You're welcome.